# mysql query for extracting "1" from "1-A","1-B",etc from a particular column

Tags: mysql, vb6

I have a table with the following structure:

```
+---------+------------+
| TableNo | ItemName   |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | X          |
| 2       | Y          |
| 1       | Z          |
| 1-A     | A          |
| 2-A     | B          |
+---------+------------+
```

I am generating a report called `SalesbyTableNo` in which a user selects from a list the `TableNo`s whose sales he wishes to see—but he can select only tables 1, 2, 3, etc: there is no option to select tables `1-A` or `2-A` (or `3-B`, `4-F` etc. which could also exist in the above shown table).

If the user selects table `1`, I wish to show all items sold on table number "1" which includes `1`, `1-A`, `1-B`, etc. I wish to get the output as below:

```
TableNo: 1  
Sold ItemNames : X,Z,A

TableNo: 2  
Sold ItemNames : Y,B
```

The following is the query which I am currently using, which gives me reports of tables `1`, `2`, `3`, etc. but does not include `1-A`, `1-B`, with included table `1`:

```
strSQL = "select TableNo,Outlet,ItemName,id, Quantity, Value,
@i:= IF(Outlet = @last_outlet and TableNo = @last_tableno, @i + 1, 1) as result, 
@last_outlet := Outlet,@last_tableno := TableNo from (SELECT  @i := 0, 
@last_outlet := NULL, @last_tableno := NULL) h 
JOIN (SELECT Outlet, TableNo,ItemName, id, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity,
SUM(Value) as Value From browsekot WHERE TableNo in " & list1_values
& " and Outlet = '" & rest.Text & "' and 
Date between '" & Format(DTPicker1.Value, "yyyy-mm-dd") 
& " ' And '" & Format(DTPicker2.Value, "yyyy-mm-dd") 
& "' GROUP BY ItemName,Outlet,TableNo ORDER BY Outlet,TableNo) i"
```

Is there a way to do this by modifying the above query?

Comment: Given that you've gone to the effort of simplifying your table and problem description (e.g. by removing other columns such as `Outlet`, `id`, `Quantitiy`, `Value`, etc.), could you not also have gone to the effort of simplifying your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fairly unclear why your tables are structured this way if the records *1-A*, *1-B*, etc are mapped to the integers 1, 2, ... anyways.

Have you considered adding an additional column?

[image: Restructured table]

If you are set on doing it this way, you can use the following to extract the proper value from *TableNo*:

```
SELECT CAST(TableNo as UNSIGNED)
```

As eggyal mentioned in the comments, this will convert TableNo to an unsigned integer up to the first non-numeric character encountered.

Of course you will have to adapt this into your code but this is the basic approach with respect to converting the text to a usable format.

Comment: Actually, one needn't bother with `INSTR()` etc since a simple `CAST(TableNo AS UNSIGNED)` will yield the integer obtained from taking all decimal characters up to the first non-decimal.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know. I only have SQL Server to test in so I'm using `CHARINDEX()` instead of `INSTR()` and trying to cast '1-A' as an INT throws an error.

Comment: Updated my answer with the simplification from @eggyal -
Thanks!

Comment: @eggyal My apologies for not simplifying the query. Ok so all I need is that if I use below query like: select* from browsekot where TableNo=`1` I should get items X, Z, A. If this can be directly done through a query else I will take another column as suggested by @msnider

Comment: @user3092228 You would do: `SELECT * FROM browsekot WHERE CAST(TableNo as UNSIGNED) = 1`

Comment: @msnider Thank you so much.Using that with my actual query gives me proper records. Just one more thing. I am using this query with SHAPE Command: rec.open " SHAPE{" & strSQL & "} AS Command1 " & _
               "COMPUTE Command1 BY Outlet,TableNo". strSQL contains the actual query. Using Shape Command separates out items of TableNo 1 and 1-A and shows them separately in the report. I wish to have all items under the TableNo 1 and dont wish to show TableNo 1-A.

Comment: @user3092228 I'm not sure I understand what you mean. It would be beneficial to see the the desired and actual outputs. If you post a link to a new question here I will take a look.

Comment: If my answer has helped you please select it as the correct answer. Thanks :)